# Detecting an installed Passbook Pass via Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, passbook, passkit

Using native code, I'm able to fetch Passbook passes created by my organization, via [PKPassLibrary's passes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PKPassLibrary/passes) method.

However, I'd like to be able to do the same via a web page, with no interaction from a native app and without any user information. So far I've only been able to find information about installing passes from the web, as well as information on the web service I must implement.

IE: Using only passTypeIdentifier, organizationName, teamIdentifier and proper certificates, is it possible to query a device for passes installed by my organization without a native app? If so, can I fetch the current pass.json from that pass? Are there any services available that do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method available to query a device for passes installed.
Your only chance is to maintain a server-side list of installed passes (easy to do with the register/unregister webservice calls) and some cookie-based registration in mobile safari.